# How to solve- Onesignal push notification not coming to Android device if the app is not opened for a while?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

In my Android application, I am using **One Signal push notification service** to send push notifications. I have done all the settings according to document as mentioned.

After setting up all these things, I have created one service class of one signal like below-

**NotificationExtenderBareBonesExample.java**

```
public class NotificationExtenderBareBonesExample extends NotificationExtenderService {

    public static String first_screen;

    @Override
    protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("NOTIFY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("notify_msg", receivedResult.payload.groupMessage);
        editor.putString("notify_key", receivedResult.payload.groupKey);
        editor.apply();

        first_screen = receivedResult.payload.groupMessage;

        return false;
    }
}
```

I have also created another class to handle the received push notification like below-

**ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler.java**

```
public class ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler {
    @Override
    public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {
        JSONObject data = notification.payload.additionalData;
        String customKey;

        if (data != null) {
            customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
            if (customKey != null)
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in my Activity class, I have initialized One Signal like below-

```
OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler())
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new MyNotificationOpenedHandler(this))
                .init();
```

At last in my **AndroidManifest** file, I have declared the service like below-

```
<service
            android:name="com.rokomari.new_package.notification_check.NotificationExtenderBareBonesExample"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

The push notification was coming, if the app is being used recently, but the problem was still there as it is mentioned in my question. So, I have checked few more solutions and applied in my project like below-

I made my application a system app and added one authentication service with that.
I also added one Broadcast-Receiver class like below-

**BootReceiver.java**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

            Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationExtenderBareBonesExample.class);
            context.startService(startServiceIntent);

            Intent notificationServiceIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationExtenderBareBonesExample.class);
            context.startService(notificationServiceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

And declared this in my **AndroidManifest** file-

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.rokomari.new_package.notification_check.BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

After doing all these I am still having the same problem.

**---- The Problem is -----**

When I am using app(opening the app) regaularly the push notification from one signal is coming whether the app is in background or not. But when I am not using the app for a while it's not coming. In addition, for some devices mainly Xiomi the push notification is not coming at all.

After making some changes in Xiomi device like below-

> *** Xiaomi  - Make sure "Auto-start" property enabled for your app in the settings.**

After changing settings, the push notification came once. But I need a solution programmatically to send push notification to cover all the devices. If it is not possible yet with One Signal, then I like to know how apps like facebook, whatsapp send push notification?

Comment: Take a look at the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64077956/android-repeated-notifications-not-working-when-app-is-closed/64108020#comment113480349_64108020

Comment: Thanks @MarkWalczak, I have seen your answer. But it would be very nice if you can provide me some examples or tutorial about the full implementation.